# How to activerecord cache in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord, memcached

How to activerecord cache in Rails 3.2.3

**stocks_controller.rb:**

```
def index
  @stocks = Rails.cache.read custom_cache_path(@res.uuid, Const::ACTIVE_STOCKS)
  if @stocks.blank?
    @stocks = Stock.only_active_stocks(params[:restaurant_id])
    Rails.cache.write custom_cache_path(@res.uuid, Const::ACTIVE_STOCKS), @stocks
  end
end

def show
  @stocks = Rails.cache.read custom_cache_path(@res.uuid, Const::ACTIVE_STOCKS)
  if @stocks.blank?
    @stocks = Stock.only_active_stocks(params[:restaurant_id])
    Rails.cache.write custom_cache_path(@res.uuid, Const::ACTIVE_STOCKS), @stocks
  end
end
```

When does a request to the show action cache return nil?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to understand your intention in the controller here, since both your show and index method have the same implementation.

With that being said, it's likely that you want to move any caching logic in to the model here, then it will be easier to isolate your problem.

Please consider the following refactor:

stocks_controller:

```
def index
  @stocks = Stock.active_for_restaurant(params[:restaurant_id])
end

def show
  @stock = Stock.fetch_from_cache(params[:id])
end
```

stock.rb:

```
def active_for_restaurant(restaurant_id)
  Rails.cache.fetch(custom_cache_path(restaurant_id, Const::ACTIVE_STOCKS)) do
    Stock.only_active_stocks(restaurant_id)
  end
end

def fetch_from_cache(id)
  Rails.cache.fetch(id, find(id))
end
```

For more info on fetch see:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: Won't `Rails.cache.fetch(id, find(id))` always hit the DB regardless of cache hit/miss?

Answer (score 0):

As rails api says - If there is no such data in the cache (a cache miss), then nil will be returned. Is that your question?

By the way, do make sure that you update the cache when the "active_stocks" change.